# Installing Bigfloat for Python

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, numbers

I am trying to install Bigfloat for python 3.4 on a Windows 8 machine. I have seen many of the other questions asking about how to install this, but nothing seems to work.

Pip and easy_install give me the error: no such file "gmp.h" I've tried the [pre-compiled versions](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy)
but I still get the same error. I was getting a "can't find vcvarsall.bat" error, but I re-installed VC 2010 and that went away. I had hoped that solving that error would let me install Bigfloat, but alas, no.

Also, I can't seem to find any good docs on installing GMP and MPFR which are required. The docs only say how to install if you're using a Linux system, which I'm not.

The only thing I have not tried yet, is using PIP as admin. I haven't done that, because I've never had to use PIP as admin before.

So far, this has been one big headache. If anyone can suggest an alternative to Bigfloat (something that can do precision math, and is used as a library) that's easier to install, I'd really appreciate it.

**Edit:**
I tried running PIP as admin, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: I'm going to try installing using PIP and easy_install with admin permissions, but I doubt it will help.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone can help? It would be really nice...

Comment: +1 for this question.  Speaking as the author of `bigfloat`, if you find easy instructions for installing `bigfloat` on Windows, I'd be very interested to know of them. :-).  Regrettably, I don't have easy access to a Windows build environment, so I've had to be content with maintaining bigfloat on OS X and Linux.  In the meantime, I'd second @casevh's suggestion to look at gmpy2.

Comment: I plan to use bigfloat (If I can get it to work on my Windows computer) to help me with a physics problem. I don't believe I can solve it by re-arranging, so I made a simple Python program to run through it with a while loop until the output is what I need. Anyway, so sum that up, I need to be able to set the number of bits of precision and, with any luck, be able to solve a problem really quickly. Python may not be the best choice for this, but its what I know.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/)? It supports GMP/MPIR (for integer and rational multiple precision arithmetic), MPFR (for real multiple precision arithmetic), and MPC (for complex multiple precision arithmetic). Pre-compiled binary installers are available at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2).

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

Comment: Yes, I just tried that. Unfortunately, I get the same error. "Cannot include gmp.h""No such file or directory"

Comment: Don't use `pip` when trying to install modules that require compiling C code on Windows. This is especially true when the required libraries (GMP/MPIR, MPFR, and MPC) can be difficult to compile. Pre-compiled versions of gmpy2 are available; for example https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2/2.0.3 BTW, detailed build instructions are included the source. See the file windows_build.txt.

Comment: I have also tried with easy_install with about the same amount of luck. I tried the pre-compiled versions you mentioned, but I still get the same error. "Cannot open include 'gmp.h' no such file or directory"

Comment: @CoilKid You don't need to use pip or easy_install. After you download and run the appropriate pre-compiled binary, gmpy2 should be ready to use. Just start Python, and type `import gmpy2`

Comment: I did that, and that installed, but bigfloat still won't install right. I think I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: @CoilKid Both gmpy2 and bigfloat provide access to the MPFR library. gmpy2 and bigfloat aren't identical but both provide access to arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic. gmpy2 should do everything you need.